# Regex: Find string unless part of another string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex pattern to parse a CSS file, looking for any instances of `$`, unless it's part of an attribute selector (`$=`, like in `[attr$=foo]`).

In other words, I'm looking for a way to find a string unless it's followed by another string. Not sure how to do that.

The script will run on node.js, v8.9.1 w/o flags, so I don't think I have Lookbehind.

Thnx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
str.match(/(\$)[^=]?/g);
```

You will have all "$" not followed by "=" in the 1st capturing group.

Comment: I think you have missed "unless" part of the question "**unless** it's part of an attribute selector"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Effectively I misread, I edited my answer, thx ;)

Comment: @Skyflo Thanks, but this gives me the `[attr$=foo]` cases and no stray `$` -- I need it the other way around.


*edit: I also post too quick... thanks @YuryTarabanko and @Skyflo